# Very basic DB query very slow

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

I've a query like this:

```
UPDATE "marketplace_question" 
   SET "answer_count" = %s 
WHERE "marketplace_question"."entry_ptr_id" = %s
```

I'm quite sure I've an index (primary key) regarding entry_ptr_id. This should take around a millisecond. I'm seeing times like 10-15 seconds even up to 110 seconds. Does this imply a big db congestion?

Plan looks like this, as much as the monitoring tells me

```
Update on marketplace_question (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=39)
-> Index Scan using marketplace_question_pkey on marketplace_question (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=39) 
   Index Cond: ?
```

Is a db query with a scan on pkey allowed to take so much time?

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`**. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Please preserve the indention and formatting of the execution plan.

Comment: @VaoTsun: there is no "actual time" in the execution plan of the question. the 8.45 in there is the _cost estimate_. Something completely different than the real execution time.

Comment: ha! I missed the word :) my bad. but then it's explain without analyze - useless here